# Python regex match two string at two different order?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match `aaa bbb` and `bbb aaa` in the following string:

```
aaa  bbb   bbb    aaa
```

using

```
match = re.search("^(?=.*(aaa))(?=.*?(bbb)).*$", subject, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
```

see https://www.regex101.com/r/vA0nB0/2

But it only match `aaa bbb`.

How can I match `bbb aaa` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below simple regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'aaa  bbb   bbb    aaa'
>>> re.findall(r'aaa.*?bbb|bbb.*?aaa', s)
['aaa  bbb', 'bbb    aaa']
```

Answer (score 3):

If Python supports conditionals:

For out of order stuff, just use a conditional.

*Note* - change the quantifier in the group to reflect how many items
are required to match. Below shows `{2}` which requires both items somewhere.
You could change it to `{1,}` - at least 1, or `+` - same thing.

`(?:.*?(?:((?(1)(?!))aaa.*?bbb)|((?(2)(?!))bbb.*?aaa))){2}`

[Formatted](http://regexformat.com):

```
 (?:
      .*? 
      (?:
           (                        # (1)
                (?(1)
                     (?!)
                )
                aaa .*? bbb 
           )
        |  (                        # (2)
                (?(2)
                     (?!)
                )
                bbb .*? aaa 
           )
      )
 ){2}
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 21 ) 
aaa  bbb   bbb    aaa
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 8 ) 
aaa  bbb
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 10 ) 
bbb    aaa
```

Comment: I think this complicated answer is a result of misunderstanding of the requirement.

Comment: @nhahtdh - True that. It did seem though he was trying to match both in one go but could not resolve the order of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, if you know that its always going to be `aaa` or `bbb`?

```
>>> a = 'aaa  bbb   bbb    aaa'
>>> match = re.findall("(aaa|bbb).+?(aaa|bbb)", a, re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
>>> match
[('aaa', 'bbb'), ('bbb', 'aaa')]
```

Here is the regex101 link : https://www.regex101.com/r/qO3uD3/1

Comment: This will match `aaa aaa` in `aaa aaa bbb`.